# How to include SELECT query in other SELECT query with LEFT JOIN inside

Tags: mysql, select

1. **`student` table**,

---

```
| student_id |  name  |  gender |
|------------|--------|---------|
|    1174    |  Steve |   male  |
|    1175    |  Jane  |  female |
|    1176    |  Mark  |   male  |
|    1177    |  Lily  |  female |
---------------------------------
```

2. **`period` table**, this table is for determine the maximum number of attendees that students can gather

---

```
| period_id | from       | to         | max_session_female | max_session_male |
|-----------|------------|------------|--------------------|------------------|
|     1     | 2018-03-02 | 2018-03-04 |         14         |         15       |
|     2     | 2018-03-05 | 2018-03-08 |         20         |         20       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

3. **`attendance` table**, dummy detail of student attendance

---

```
| student_id | period_id |    date    | tapping_time | session |
|------------|-----------|------------|--------------|---------|
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   15:30:49   |    C    |
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   19:56:15   |    F    |
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   05:10:20   |    E    |
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   12:28:54   |    B    |
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   15:31:12   |    C    |
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   12:26:33   |    B    |
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   15:39:06   |    C    |
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   18:32:40   |    E    |
|   1174     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   19:56:09   |    F    |
|   1174     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   05:14:55   |    E    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   12:27:29   |    B    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   19:53:19   |    F    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   12:25:45   |    B    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   12:29:41   |    B    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   15:32:14   |    E    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   20:24:03   |    F    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   05:15:13   |    C    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   12:36:19   |    B    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   15:38:20   |    C    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   19:52:09   |    F    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   05:14:24   |    C    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   12:29:26   |    B    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   15:31:48   |    C    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   19:55:41   |    F    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   12:29:52   |    B    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   15:40:39   |    C    |
|   1175     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   19:53:18   |    F    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   05:12:05   |    A    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   12:29:27   |    B    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   15:28:16   |    C    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   19:55:52   |    F    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   05:15:10   |    A    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   12:32:10   |    B    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   15:33:11   |    C    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   20:13:48   |    F    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   05:13:25   |    A    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   12:28:13   |    B    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   15:37:28   |    C    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   20:23:06   |    F    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   05:11:47   |    A    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   12:31:43   |    B    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   15:28:29   |    C    |
|   1175     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   20:21:29   |    F    |
|   1176     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   20:50:43   |    F    |
|   1176     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   19:54:32   |    F    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   05:13:30   |    A    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   12:38:29   |    B    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-02 |   19:53:38   |    F    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   05:12:33   |    A    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   12:34:48   |    B    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   15:39:05   |    C    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-03 |   20:00:51   |    F    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   05:10:59   |    A    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   12:33:56   |    B    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   15:39:09   |    C    |
|   1177     |    1      | 2018-03-04 |   19:48:59   |    F    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   05:12:15   |    A    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   12:30:53   |    B    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   15:34:53   |    C    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-05 |   19:53:19   |    F    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   05:12:56   |    A    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   12:30:03   |    B    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   15:31:00   |    C    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-06 |   19:52:40   |    F    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   05:12:30   |    A    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   12:34:48   |    B    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   15:40:34   |    C    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-07 |   19:53:47   |    F    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   05:11:21   |    A    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   12:35:21   |    B    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   15:36:26   |    C    |
|   1177     |    2      | 2018-03-08 |   19:52:32   |    F    |
```

I've found a query to calculate an average score of students based on gender,
Women :

```
SELECT (COUNT(a.tapping_time)/2)/p.max_session_female*100 AS 'women_score' 
FROM period p
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON p.period_id = a.period_id
LEFT JOIN student s ON a.student_id = a.student_id
WHERE s.gender = 'female'
GROUP BY p.period_id
```

Men :

```
SELECT (COUNT(a.tapping_time)/2)/p.max_session_male*100 AS 'men_score ' 
FROM period p
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON p.period_id = a.period_id
LEFT JOIN student s ON a.student_id = a.student_id
WHERE s.gender = 'male'
GROUP BY p.period_id
```

but how to make the score in a table ?

**Desired result** :

```
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| period_id | from       | to         | total_att | women_score | men_score |
|-----------|------------|------------|-----------|-------------|-----------|
|     1     | 2018-03-02 | 2018-03-04 |    31     |     78      |     30    |
|     2     | 2018-03-05 | 2018-03-08 |    41     |     95      |     7.5   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: the maximum number of attendees that students can gather - eh?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    period_id,
    MIN(date) AS `from`,
    MAX(date) AS `to`,
    COUNT(*) AS total_att,
    100 * COUNT(CASE WHEN s.gender = 'male'
               THEN a.tapping_time END) / p.max_session_male AS male_score,
    100 * COUNT(CASE WHEN s.gender = 'female'
               THEN a.tapping_time END) / p.max_session_female AS female_score
FROM period p
LEFT JOIN attendance a
    ON p.period_id = a.period_id
LEFT JOIN student s
    ON a.student_id = a.student_id
GROUP BY p.period_id;
```

Note that selecting the `max_session_male` and `max_session_female` columns while grouping by `period_id` might be suspicious.  But if `period_id` is the primary key of fhe `period` table, then it is OK.

Comment: i'm sorry @Tim the result does not match what I need, it's not calculate the score number

Comment: @codefighter I updated my answer to match exactly your expected output.  The crux of my answer remains to use conditional aggregation.